# Protobuf dynamic and static library

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have two custom protobuf libraries. One is dynamic, other is static.
Static lib has a message:

```
message DataType
{
    int number = 1;
    string name_1 = 2;
    string name_2 = 3;
    string name_3 = 4;
}

// The dynamic lib has a message:
message MyMessage
{
    DataType type = 1;
}
```

I build dynamic proto lib with linking static proto lib to it.
Then I build exe application to which I link dynamic proto lib.

The problem is that when I set one of name_1, name_2 or name_3, they all have this value. I think all these strings have same buffer.
If to convert dynamic lib to static, then problem disappears.
Could anyone explain me what is wrong with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If a field is not set then it should return empty string. Please check the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#proto3_string).

If you are using version 2 you can query whether the field is set by `has_name_x()`.

By the way there are several ways to set a value:

- The simplest creates a copy: `void set_name_x(const string& value)`
- In case of `C++11` you can move a string value: `void set_name_x(string&& value)`
- You can pass pointer: `void set_allocated_name_x(string* value)`
- You can get the pointer to the stored string: `string* mutable_name_x()`

I would advice to get familiar with protobuf and let it manage memory and use `set_name_x`. If it is not sufficient you can optimize your code with manual memory management.